# Decomposition and loss of dependencies

Tags: relational-theory, dependencies

I'm lost in the sea with the following example of decomposition without loss of dependencies...

Let be the dependencies `F= {A → BC, C → AD}` R is decomposed in `R¹(A,B,C)` & `R²(A,D)` I want to know if such a decomposition is without loss of dependencies and without loss of information.

I understand that it is without loss of information but why is it without loss of dependencies?

It is said so because

- `F¹={A → BC, C → A, C → B}` because `C → A` and `C → B` since
  decomposition of `A → BC`. **I don't understand why `C → A` and `C →
  B`**
- `F²={A → D}` **but why**? `A → BC, C → AD` therefore `A → AD`, no?

C → D shouldn't be lost  but isn't in F¹ nor in F². Why is it important to say that?

`C → A` (from F¹) and `A → D` (from F²) therefore, `C → D`

The result which I don't understand at all is that it is without loss of dependencies...